# Reference a variable multiple times with SLF4J

Tags: java, slf4j

I want to reference a variable multiple times using SLF4J:

```
log.debug("The xml was <{}>slf4j</{}>", "log");
```

Would output `The xml was <log>slf4j</log>`.

Is that possible? The [documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter.html) seems to suggest only the very simple {} formatting pattern is supported.

An answer of "no you can't" is in my mind a perfectly valid answer and will be accepted if it is somehow able to be confirmed.

Comment: The documentation says that they simplified the formatting pattern in order to achieve much better performance. So I guess, that's all there is. You'll have to pass the variable in twice (or think about phrasing the message in a way that does not require repetition).